# Hiding columns in DataGrid and 'Code generation for property FormatInfo failed'

Tags: c#, interface, datagrid, .net-3.5

In the begginig I would like to mark that I am programing this on .NET v 3.5 for MobileCE.

My first problem is I can not hide column in DataGrid. I am setting on DataGrid in properties in TableStyles required things. In editor I can see this changes because I can see only this columns I define in TableStyles but when I send it on device all columns are showed.

[Here in MappingName I set name of class that contains definition of loading data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEayz.png)

[This is one of 4 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXMuX.png)

This is my data definition:

```
   class Trasnd
   {
        public string REF { get; set; }
        public string NR { get; set; }
        public string SYM { get; set; }
        public string DATE { get; set; }        

        internal static List<Trasnd> getDataWs()
        {
            ......
        }

    }
```

And next I use this code to load data to DataGrid (loaded corectly)

```
dataGrid1.DataSource = Trasnd.getDataWs();
```

Trying to hiding columns from code doesn't work either. I have no idea how to do that.

And the second problem is when I change MappingName in property and I want to save project:

```
Code generation for property 'FormatInfo' failed. Error was: 'Object 
reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I should use name of class (with data definition) or different name and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517252/visual-studio-shows-endless-messages-code-generation-for-property-valuemember

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide columns , use this code

```
int Column_Index = 2;
dataGrid1.Columns[Column_Index].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Here is a problem because I cant use DataGridView. Maybe you know how can I do that? I do not have this item in toolbox.

Comment: https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/introduction-adding-controls-to-the-toolbox

Answer (score 0):

By Code behind you can do like this

if(grdEmployee.Columns.Count>0)
grdEmployee.Columns[0].Visible =false;

with CSS :

.hideGridColumn
        {
            display: none;
        }